# Will canceling an app purchase in play delete the app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid application in the play store. There are no in-app purchases, the app itself is charged.
I noticed a user bought the app and then immediately cancelled the purchase. 
What happens with the app which he already downloaded? Will it still be available on his phone?
I can not seem to find any information on this, everything I found is about in-app purchases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about play store behaviour instead of programming

Comment: why don't you test it on your own with any other device?

Answer (score 0):

So in this case firstly the user pays for the app and then he would be able to go for the download link. So if he cancel the payment he would not be able to download it.